# Define operator< for a c++ set of pointers

Tags: c++, set

I'm trying to write c++ STL set which keeps pointers to my custom class. But I don't understand how to overload < operator when I work with pointers, not the objects of the class.

I read that if we overload < operator which is used by set for comparison. But when I store pointers this function is not called at all. That means that set compares pointers to objects differently from objects.

I came across the trick when you create a struct with operator() function and pass it to the set, like `set<Object, Comparator>`. But I still don't understand how it works, since set only uses less-comparison.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    int x;

    public:
    Node(int x)
    {
        this->x = x;
    }

    bool operator<(const Node& n) const
    {
        cout << "inside operator<" << endl;
        return this->x < n.x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    set<Node*> s;

    Node n1(10);
    Node n2(11);

    s.insert(&n1);

    auto res = s.find(&n1);
    if (res == s.end())
    {
        cout << "not found";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "found";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code results with `found`. Why?

I would like to learn:

- How use `set` with pointers.
- How to overload `operator<` properly.

Comment: You compare *the pointers* and not the data they point to. You need to overload `bool operator<(Node*, Node*)` One reason to be wary of containers (especially associative containers) of pointers.

Comment: How and where to overload operator< for Node pointers?

Comment: It needs to be done in the same namespace where you define the class you want to compare. In your example it needs to be done at the global scope (since `Node` is defined in the global scope). As for how, just let the operator compare the *object* (as in `return *n1 < *n2;` which will invoke your existing operator).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *probably don't* want to change `bool operator <(Node *, Node *)`. Instead you should look to supplying a non-default *Compare* to your `set`.

```
template <typename T>
struct pointee_less
{
    bool operator()(T* lhs, T* rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs && rhs) ? std::less<T>{}(*lhs, *rhs) : std::less<T*>{}(lhs, rhs);
    }
}

template <typename T>
using pointer_set = std::set<T*, pointee_less<T>>;

int main()
{
    pointer_set<Node> s;

    Node n1(10);
    Node n2(11);

    s.insert(&n1);

    auto res = s.find(&n1);
    if (res == s.end())
    {
        cout << "not found";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "found";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For genericity and debuggability (operator< has some dark corner-cases, pointers can be null pointers), I would use `assert(lhs && rhs); return std::less()(*lhs, *rhs);`. Alternatively allow null pointers and use `return lhs && rhs ? std::less(*lhs, *rhs) : !lhs && rhs;` Also add `constexpr` and look into forwarding noexcept.

Comment: I am not sure if you can add a `nullptr` to the set, and it sounds strange to look for a `nullptr` in the set. But unless you are totally sure that either of those will ever happen, then perhaps `pointee_less` could use a couple of null checks before dereferencing the pointers.